# Сравнение "таблиц".

Tags: php, mysql

Имеется:

```
1)Есть таблица в которой содержится 1 поле.(Допустим ID).(исходная таблица\старые данные)
2)Есть массив в котором содержатся значения.(Список через запятую например этих самых айди).(Новая таблица\Новые данные).
```

Задача:

```
1) Найти все записи которые остались в таблице.
2) Найти все удаленные записи.
3) Найти все добавленые записи.
```

Пояснения:

```
у меня есть таблица в базе, которая при обновлении просто удалялась, и записывалась заного из новых данных, хочу исправить ситуацию и сделать это как мне кажется нормально.
1)удалить записи которых нет в новом варианте(и отметить это удаление в логе).
2)Добавить новые записи(также отметить в логе).
3)Модифицировать записи у которых обновились данные(тотже айди но данные новые) и внести это в лог.
```

Вопросы:

```
1) Как лучше искать пересечения таблиц(в каком порядке и на стороне php или MySQL)
2) Если используем MySQL что лучше временная таблица(для новых записей) или выборка вида Select id from `table` where id [not] in({список через запятую айди из новой таблицы});
3) Как лучше(оптимальней) обновить записи у которых тот же айди но разные данные?
  a) Удалить старые, затем вставить новые;
  b) попытатся вставить новые при совпадении ключей заменить значения?
  c) Отдельный запрос Update на каждую запись?.
  d) Что то еще..
```

p.s. Каждая из таблиц может содержать 1-200 записей(айди).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете копию оригинальной таблицы. Без автоинкремента id. 
Заносите туда данные. В цикле генерите записи для insert'а: `'(id, field1, field2), (id, field1, field2),...'` Вставляете их одним запросом. `` insert into `tab_copy` values $values; `` Если данных много, то можно несколькими запросами.

Тогда

1. Записи, которые остались

   ```
   select tc.id 
   from tab t 
     join tab_copy tc on 
       tc.id = t.id
   ```
2. Удаленные

   ```
   select t.id
   from tab t 
     left join tab_copy tc on 
       tc.id = t.id 
   where
     tc.id is null
   ```
3. Добавленные аналогично удаленным, только обратное соединение

   ```
   select tc.id
   from tab t 
     right join tab_copy tc on 
       tc.id = t.id 
   where
     t.id is null
   ```
4. insert, update, delete делается в соответствии с этими запросами. т.е. данные которые обновлять получаете первым запросом, удалять - во втором запросе, добавлять в третьем.

php тут нужен только чтоб сформировать таблицу с нужными данными, остальное все через sql.

Comment: Спасиб за подсказки но несовсем то.
на 1 вопрос ответ получен, временная таблица. и совпадения на стороне бд искать.
по второму вопросу джоин будет лучше нежели ...[not] in (select id from temp_table)?

и по третему вопросу совсем не в тему)(или про это вообще нет у вас в посте)..

Comment: Третий вопрос(с примерами чтоб было понятней):
    
    Для каждой уже имеющейся записи делать отдельный запрос вида 
    UPDATE `table` set field1='val', field2='val2';

    или запрос вида
    Insert into `table`(id,field1,field2) values(1,'val','val2'),(2,'val','val2').... on duplicate key set field1=VALUE(field1),field2=VAlUE(field2);
    

    или вообще запрос на удаление всех данных delete from `table` where id in (перечень записей к обновлению) и затем вставить Insert into `table`(id,field1,field2) values(1,'val','val2'),(2,'val','val2')

В этом заключался третий вопрос,

Comment: нумерация у меня по задачам была. 4-я ответ на все последущее.  
not in или join не принципиально. на 200 записях разницы не заметите ни в лучшую ни в худшую сторону. при not in субд создаст временную таблицу и с ней будет работать. при join'е врем.таблица создаваться не будет. при желании можно посмотреть план запроса, если есть желание разобраться досконально.  
решение всех задач, тут исходит из таблицы копии. т.е. как только вы ее создадите и наполните, данными можно вертеть как угодно, без php и неоптимальных запросов (типа на каждую строку по update'у).

Comment: Тогда мне непонятно как залить в базу(обновить записи) из новой таблицы, без нескольких запросов. если не затруднит, можно ли контакт(скайп\аська) поясните сей момент. приведу кусок кода как оно есть сейчас.

Comment: изменения:

    update tab t 
      join tab_copy tc on 
        tc.id = t.id
    set t.field1 = tc.field1, t.field2 = tc.field2...

или on duplicate тоже нормально, добавление соответственно on duplicate уже тоже готово.  
удаление:

    delete tab from tab t 
      left join tab_copy tc on 
        tc.id = t.id 
      where
        tc.id is null

ЗЫ не проверял синтаксис.

Comment: Если on duplicate тоже нормально то так и сделаю) синтаксис не важен) если что и сам поправлю) мануалы читать умею, но там нет тестов(что лучше что хуже). вот и обращаюс сюда))

На данный момент просто уже много чего под on duplicate заготовлено а не на обновление из второй таблицы. да и временная таблица содержит только айди.


p.s. - пхп тут тоже очень нужен) запись идет еще и в таблицу лога о которой пару дней назад был вопрос от меня) на пхп реализована логика добавления туда.